# Linq into keyword not working in EF Core 8

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

This is my query:

```
var loadadminsearchdb = (
    from LA in _logisticsRMISContext.LoadAdmin
    join CA in _logisticsRMISContext.ChargesAdmin
        on new { a = LA.UserName, b = LA.CompanyCode } equals new
        {
            a = CA.UserName,
            b = CA.CompanyCode
        }
        into CA_join
    from j2 in CA_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join DA in _logisticsRMISContext.DepartmentAdmin on j2.UserName equals DA.UserName into DA_join
    from k2 in DA_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where LA.ActiveFlag == true && LA.CompanyCode == CompanyCode
    group new { j2, LA, k2 } by new
    {
        LA.UserName,
        LA.EmailAddress,
        LA.DisplayName,
        LA.CompanyCodeNavigation.CompanyName,
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.UserName,
        g.Key.EmailAddress,
        g.Key.DisplayName,
        g.Key.CompanyName,
        loadspcount = g.Select(x => x.LA.SalesPersonID).Distinct().Count(),
        chargesspcount = g.Where(x => x.j2.SalesPersonID != null && x.j2.ActiveFlag == true)
            .Select(x => x.j2.SalesPersonID)
            .Distinct()
            .Count(),
        departmentcount = g.Where(x => x.k2.DepartmentID != null && x.k2.ActiveFlag == true)
            .Select(x => x.k2.DepartmentID)
            .Distinct()
            .Count()
    }
).ToList();
```

This used to work in Entity Framework .Net framework version but now I am migrating the application to .Net Core and when I run it I get the error as shown below:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<LoadAdmin>()
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<ChargesAdmin>(), 
        outerKeySelector: LA => new { 
            a = LA.UserName, 
            b = LA.CompanyCode
         }, 
        innerKeySelector: CA => new { 
            a = CA.UserName, 
            b = CA.CompanyCode
         }, 
        resultSelector: (LA, j2) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = new { 
                LA = LA, 
                CA_join = CA_join
             }, 
            j2 = j2
         })
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: __p_0
            .AsQueryable(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier1.j2.UserName, 
        innerKeySelector: DA => DA.UserName, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, k2) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 = new { 
                <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, 
                DA_join = DA_join
             }, 
            k2 = k2
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
```

How can I rewrite this query so it works in the latest EF Core?

Comment: @YongShun: Hey - sorry I was testing something so it came in. I have now removed it and get the same error. The error is related to the bug in EF Core: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19930. Any easy way to do is welcome. I tried to use the author's ConvertGroupJoins but it's not working and has it's own set of issues.

Comment: What happens if you try `join DA in _logisticsRMISContext.DepartmentAdmin on LA.UserName equals.....` Also given you are grouping by all columns in `LA` anyway, you could use a correlated subquery instead of normal grouping.

Comment: Try comment out one by one last projection properties. I'm not sure that EF Core can translate this.

Comment: you could create a database view, That way your EF-query will be a simple `SELECT ... FROM ...`, and any (future) upgrades might be easier.

Comment: @Charlieface could you please share example?